# Why doesn't my compiler like this statement?

Tags: c++

This is supposed to return false if a character in the string isn't a letter or an apostrophe. Any idea why it doesn't work? And is there a better way that I can write it? I'm trying to write code like a C++ purist.

```
for (std::string::const_iterator it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); ++it)
    if ((*it < 'a' || *it >'z') && (*it > 'A' || *it < 'Z') && (*it != ''''))
        return false;
```

Comment: what is `''''` supposed to be? An empty string? Or literally a string that contains two single quotes?

Comment: `''''` <-- What is that supposed to be? If you want I'm assuming you meant `"\'\'"`

Comment: I think they wanted the single quote character, `'\''`

Comment: Incidentally, I recall `''''` being the single quote constant in Pascal and some dialects of assembly.

Comment: @BrianBi: Yup. Also in SQL.

Answer (score 7):

I see two mistakes:

- `''''` should be `'\''`.
- `*it > 'A' || *it < 'Z'` should be `*it < 'A' || *it > 'Z'`.